# Always positioning my jQuery tooltip in the center of the parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I wrote this plugin but I'm having issues trying to position the tooltip so that it's completely centered above the parent container. I'm currently just calculating the width of the parent container that it's in and finding out where that is by getting it's `left` position, but it's always not completely centered.

Any ideas?

```
(function($) {
    var toolTip = {
        init: function() {
            this.each(function() {
                var $that = $(this);
                // our boolean object to check if it already exists on the page
                var $toolSpan = $('<div class="tooltip"><span class="tooltip_arrow"></span></div>');

                var preloadImages = function() {
                    var tempImage = new Image();
                    tempImage.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/K5ynr.png';
                    tempImage = null;
                };
                preloadImages();
                $that.mouseover(function() {
                    var $altText = $that.attr('alt');
                    var $parentWidth = $that.parent().width();
                    var $parentPos = $that.parent().position();
                    var $parentPosY = $parentPos.top;
                    var $parentPosX = $parentPos.left;

                        $that.parent().after($toolSpan);
                        $toolSpan.prepend($altText);
                        $that.parent().next($toolSpan).css('top', $parentPosY - 30).css('left', $parentPosX).fadeIn();

                        var $toolSpanWidth = $that.parent().outerWidth();
                        $that.parent().next('.tooltip').children('.tooltip_arrow').css('left', $toolSpanWidth / 2).fadeIn();
                }).mouseout(function() {
                    $that.parent().next($toolSpan).text('').hide().remove();
                });
            });
        } /* end init */
    };
    $.fn.toolTip = toolTip.init;
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QH8dy/2/

Comment: try using `offset()` instead of `position()`

Comment: @elclanrs That didn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go - centered, all working, code a bit cleaner ...

http://jsfiddle.net/PBpWj/

though it can potentially go off screen if the tip text is too wide.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'm gonna make a case for that in the next iteration. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you intention is so that the tooltip container is center aligned above the link containers (in this case the `wrapper`s). Try modifying the following line of code:

```
$that.parent().next($toolSpan)
    .css('top', $parentPosY - 30)
    .css('left', $parentPosX + ($parentWidth/2) - ($toolSpan.width()/2))
    .fadeIn();
```

See it at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/QH8dy/4/).